# Please support the Area 51 Proposal for Greek!

Tags: discussion

Click [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123680/greek-language?referrer=ZjJjMTU4YmIwMGIxZGM1MTNjZjRjNWIzNzIwMTZjOTA3MWQ1MTM4ZjYyNWM3YTM3N2UyNmM0M2JlMDk4ZTUzYwyBb88xT29yLS42NvBVZVsA1Gm4xLC4z6pPBoxcuuUr0) to support the 4th try!

For the record, here's the [1st attempt by someone else](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101509/greek-language) and [my 2nd](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/117994/greek-language), [3rd](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/120649/greek-language?referrer=6xe40guy8MPh_bKhvH06tg2) attempt by me.

Comment: You might consider including some reasoning to support your plea. *Why* should I "support" a proposal for a Greek SE? What do you mean by "support"? Does it go beyond thinking vaguely kind thoughts?

Comment: @user6726 "support" in this context involves some degree of active participation in that SE site. More details here: https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq. While I would like to see Greek get its own SE site, being such a culturally important language, I don't see myself participating there at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the proposal has been deleted already.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the proposal has been deleted

Answer (score 1):

https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

Area51 seems to be devoid of moderators as of this writing. Maybe we can come back to this in a few months' time, after things have stabilized a bit at Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

The proposal has been deleted.